# Regex for extracting folder name from absolute path(Linux)

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, regexp-replace

I am using regex function in Apache Nifi to find the folder name in file path but it doesn't seem to give me correct result

I want to parse out "state" and "date" with two different regex from this file path

`/upload/main/state/02022021/`

This was the regex i used

`${ "absolute.path":replaceFirst( ".*[/\\\\]{1}([a-zA-Z]+)[/\\\\]{1}(\d{8}).?$", "$1") }`
`${"absolute.path":replaceFirst(".*(\d{8}).+$", "$1")}`

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using

```java
state = ${"absolute.path":replaceFirst(".*[/\\\\]([^\\\\/]+)[/\\\\]\\d{8}[/\\\\]?$", "$1")}
date  = ${"absolute.path":replaceFirst(".*[/\\\\](\\d{8})[\\\\/]?$", "$1")}
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/DQxdXe/1/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/DQxdXe/2/).

The point is to

1. Make sure the regex matches the entire input string
2. Make sure each backslash that creates a regex escape (like `\d`, `\\`) is also escaped
3. Put parentheses around the part of a match you want to extract
4. Use `$1` in the replacement to extract that part.

Here is the first pattern description:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `[/\\]` - a `/` or `\` char
- `(\d{8})` - Capturing group (referred to with the help of `$1` from the replacement pattern): eight digits
- `[\\\\/]?` - an optional `/` or `\` char
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

I would use these two expressions if the occurrences are always in the same place:

- for the date in last position `(?<=\/)[^\/]*?(?=\/$)`
- for state in the second to last position `(?<=\/)[^\/]*?(?=\/[^\/]*?\/$)`

Also, you can change .* for something more specific to increase reliability.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in getting values and nothing specific with approach then try below,

```
state = ${absolute.path:getDelimitedField(4, '/')}
date  = ${absolute.path:getDelimitedField(5, '/')}
```

Refer -[Nifi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield)